# What does template<typename T, T> mean?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, member-pointers

I was reading this prehistoric metaprogam example to detect whether a class supports member find. (or any other member).

```
template<typename T>
class DetectFind
{
    struct Fallback { int find; }; 
    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };

    template<typename U, U> struct Check;

    typedef char Yes[1];  
    typedef char No[2]; 

    template<typename U>
    static No& func(Check<int Fallback::*, &U::find>*);

    template<typename U>
    static Yes& func(...);

public:
    typedef DetectFind type;
    enum { value = sizeof(func<Derived>(0)) == sizeof(Yes) };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << DetectFind<std::vector<int> >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout<< DetectFind<std::set<int> >::value << std::endl;
}
```

Intuitively I do understand the aim behind this, but if someone would ask me to write same thing from scratch after 10 days, I maybe will fail this.
The reason for that is that I do not fully understand the syntactical and language stretch that is used here.
Can someone please explain what the following syntaxes mean?

1. `Check<int Fallback::*, &U::find>*`  (I know its trying to benefit from SFIANE here, but how is this detecting the existence of find, I beleive this is linked to the second question as well)
2. `template<typename U, U> struct Check;`

The program outputs 0  1 as predicted;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let us consider the struct `Derived`. Since it derives from `Fallback` it certainly contains a int field `find`, and possibly a member function `find`, whose existence is what you want to check.

As noted in the answer above, in the declaration of the `struct Check`, the first template parameter is as type, and the second is a non-type parameter, of the type given by the first parameter.

Given that, let us examine the two overloads of `func`. The first overload takes a pointer to a `Check` struct, whose first template parameters is a type equal to pointer-to-int member of `Fallback` (`int Fallback::*`). The second template parameter is then interpreted as a pointer-to-int member with value is `&U::find`.
Given `U = Derived`, if `T` contains a `find` member function, this second parameter of `Check` is ambiguous, as it could also refer to the `int find` inherited by `Fallback`. By SFINAE, this overload of `func` will be then discarded.

The second `func` overload is always well defined. But if the first overload is not discarded, the second one is less specialized, so the the compiler will choose the first overload.

In summary: if `U` in `template <typename U> func` contains a member function `find`, the compiler chooses the second overload of `func`. If the member function `find` is absent, the compiler chooses the first overload.

Finally, the value of `DetectFind` is determined by the size of the returning type of the chosen `func`, which depending on the overload is a char array of size 1 or 2. From there, you get which overload of `func` is chosen, and from the discussion above, whether `T` has a member function `find` or not.

Answer (score 7):

`template<typename U, U>` means there are two template arguments: an arbitrary type U, and an unnamed non-type template argument (eg. a value argument) whose type is U. As an example, an `int` scenario would be `ClassName<int,42>`.

In your example, the type `U` is a pointer to `int` member, and the value is the address of an `int` member.

Answer (score 1):

Let's firstly cover the declaration of `struct Check`;
`template<typename U,U> struct Check` means a that template arguments are

1. An ordinary type `U`
2. An object of type `U`, which doesn't have name.

`Check<int Fallback::*, &U::find>*` is a little bit more confusing.

The first template argument is a [pointer to member.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members), in this case it stands for a pointer to an member of `class Fallback` of type `int`, which would have allowed us to write something like this.

```
Fallback obj{10};
int Fallback::* find_ptr = &Fallback::find;
std::cout << obj.*find << std::endl;   //prints 10, note: ".*" is a separate operator
```

The second argument of the template is the address of the member of `class U`, as the initial declaration of `struct Check` suggested.